# Reading XML nodes and add to datagrid

Tags: c#, xml

I have a XML file with settings. I would like to read the the `name` and `value`of all `CollectionEntry` nodes and add them to a DataGrid.

I think a good way is to use a List and fill it with the name and values of the XML file and then add it to the DataGrid, like this:

```
List<Buffer> buffers = new List<Buffer>();
buffers.Add(new Buffer(){bufferName="username_testuser1",bufferValue="testuser2"});
bufferGrid.DataSource = buffers;

public class Buffer
{
  public string bufferName { get; set; }
  public string bufferValue { get; set; }
}
```

But how can I read the specific `CollectionEntry` values? This is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Settings xmlns="Namespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Category name="Commander">
    <Category name="ManualTestExecution">
      <Setting name="WindowLocation" legacyPath="Commander.GUI.ManualTestExecution.WindowLocation">336,263</Setting>
      <Setting name="WindowSize" legacyPath="Commander.GUI.ManualTestExecution.WindowSize">732,451</Setting>
    </Category>
  </Category>
  <Category name="Engine">
    <Setting name="Key Delay" legacyPath="BaseSettings.keyDelay">1</Setting>
    <Setting name="Wait Intermediate" legacyPath="BaseSettings.waitIntermediate">5000</Setting>
    <Setting name="Report Successful Execution of" legacyPath="XML.OutputLogLevel">2</Setting>
    <Collection name="Buffer" legacyPath="Buffer.Local">
      <CollectionEntry name="username_testuser1">testuser2</CollectionEntry>
      <CollectionEntry name="password_testuser1">!Welcome099</CollectionEntry>
      <CollectionEntry name="username_testuser2">testuser2</CollectionEntry>
    </Collection>
  </Category>
</Settings>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using LINQ to XML you can use

```
XNamespace df = "Namespace";

List<Buffer> buffers = new List<Buffer>(from entry in XDocument.Load("yourFile.xml").Descendants(df + "CollectionEntry") select new Buffer( bufferName = (string)entry.Attribute("name"), bufferValue = (string)entry));
```

Comment: I get an error: `XDocument is a type but is used like a variable`